# Midvatten plugin used with qgis2threejs

Tags: qgis, 3d, qgis2threejs, midvatten

I have been using QGIS 2.8.1 to map an archaeological project and I have now installed [Midvatten](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/midvatten/) 1.4.6 with the aim of visualizing the stratigraphy from various test pits using qgis2threejs.

After creating the Midvatten database, I have made up some dummy test data for a single pit, loaded the pit name as "obsid" and its position into table "obs points" and the test stratigraphy data into "stratigraphy".  By selecting the test pit, I can obtain a stratigraphy plot from Midvatten.

My problem arises when I use "Midvatten> Utilities> **Prepare 3D-data for Qgis2threejs plugin**".  I see that the data layers are generated but the stratigraphy does not appear in the qgis2threejs visualization and on inspection I find that the 3D-data tables are completely empty of any attributes.

Comment: I have the same problem but it doesn't fix even if I repalce null values in "TOC-GS" and "ground surface"...probably i'm doing someting wrong but i don't know where; the plugin populate the table "strat_obs_p_for_qgsi2threejs" but any record appear in the other tables... The table stratigraphy is correct (I suppose), when I plot a 2d stratigraphy it works...have you any idea? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi @francesco . Are the data layers generated by the Midvatten plugin populated with the stratigraphy you have entered in "stratigraphy"? If so, I don't know why it will not display.  Possibly you have not set up the layers correctly for display in the qgis2threejs plugin,  This tutorial gives guidance on the configuration of the plugin:   https://github.com/jkall/qgis-midvatten-plugin/wiki/7.-Utilities .

Answer (score 2):

I have discovered that I need to add more data to the table "obs points".  Specifically, I replaced the NULL values in columns "TOC-GS" and "ground surface" with figure zero, then all seemed to work.  These measurements seem to relate to borehole drilling which didn't have a direct application to the excavated pits my data applies to.